# automating decompile / recompile in ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

my front end from time to time is getting larger. i am building new reports and forms.

i know that remou suggests to decompile and compile every so often to make sure nothing is corrupt. can i automate this decompile/ recompile process?

Comment: Decompiling is not the real answer -- compacting is. An occasional deompile can get you a smaller file, but it's never all that big a difference.

Comment: @ David-W-Fenton I find that if you are intensively working with code & objects, regular decompiling helps prevent problems. Once an application is completed, it is not so important.

Comment: I spend an entire day working intensively in code and decompile only once or twice during that entire period. I'm a big promoter of decompile, but don't think it's necessary to do it as often as you seem to me to be suggesting.

Comment: How often do you think I am suggesting? Once or twice a day is a lot more than occasional, I reckon.

Comment: I've lost the context, which seems to be on some other SO post, but I thought you were suggesting a frequency much greater than that. FWIW, that's the frequency I've always explicitly suggested -- I just thought you were recommending something more than that. I still don't think code is a big contributer to bloat, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of automation do you have in mind?

**Edit**: If you intend to automate this, don't automate decompile in isolation; include backup and compact with decompile.

You could try something like this as one line in a BAT file, changing the paths to match your version of msaccess.exe and your database file:

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft office\office\msaccess.exe" /decompile
"c:\MyPath\MyDatabase.mdb"
```

Danny Lesandrini discussed other options for decompile and other maintenance type stuff in a *Database Journal* article: [Microsoft Access File Backup and Maintenance Options](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3879376/Microsoft-Access-File-Backup-and-Maintenance-Options.htm)

I think he mentioned the method I use ... a decompile context menu option in Windows Explorer.  You can find more information including a REG file at [Getting the Decompile and Compact context menu options](http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0039.htm)

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to do this without a full set of actions, that is, back-up, decompile, compact & repair.

Comment: Right, that's why I tried to get him to tell us more about what he intends to automate.  That shortcut menu includes both compact and decompile options.  I won't ever use either of them without a fresh backup first.