# MS Access 2010/2013 Transition Issues

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

So currently my boss and I are the two employees that work on our company's access database.  I just got Office 2013 on my computer and he is will working with 2010.  We have ran into some inexplicable bugs with the database.

Most of these can be fixed by just copying an old version of a form or report into the database when it fails; however, it is quite disconcerting when we spend hours trying to discover why something is wrong and are able to fix it without explaining why.

Most of the issues so far have occurred when I am using the db in Access 2013.  So far the issues have been:

- Access occasionally crashes and restarts when I am working in the VB code
- Some forms bug out for no reason.  It yet again occurs when I am working in the VB code if there is a compile erro.  To further explain the "bugging out", the form usually contains about 2000 separate forms that you can search through, but when it bugs out it will only show one blank form.  At first I panicked thinking all the table's data was gone, but nothing changed the table
- There have been other hiccups, but nothing noteworthy besides these two

I guess my question is if anyone else has had issues along these lines, or if they knew of any other known issues.  I tried to research errors people have been having, but I couldn't find anything besides Microsoft's official release of what features were being deleted.

As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please delineate who experiences what: Access 2010 user vs Access 2013 user. Are you sure Access crashes while you work in code or when code is running? What is your environment -local, LAN, or VPN? Do not work in internet folders (Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, etc.) or flash drives. Also, no form can have 2,000 separate forms. The highest number of controls any one form can have is around 750 but depends on [type](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=211166). And check 32-bit vs 64-bit OS differences.

Comment: The issues were happening on the 2013 version

Comment: Tyler, I work in MS Access 2010, but virtually all my clients are in 2013. I have not had one issue to date and certainly nothing as you describe. I fundamentally believe it is you or your co-workers' CPU/network environment and not the software. Both versions use same file format (.accdb) with slightly different features but the essential core is intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2010, but I worked with a consultant who worked on the same project in 2013. I too, saw some behavior that looked like version related bugs, but nothing definite.

Responding to your list:

- Access occasionally crashes and restarts when I am working in the VB code -- *This has happened to me in every version of Access I have used, from 97 to 2010.*
- Some forms bug out for no reason. It yet again occurs when I am working in the VB code if there is a compile error... -- *If the compile error is severe enough to lose project state, this is not surprising.*

Recommendations:

1. Decompile your application front-end occasionally, especially when 'weird' errors show up. See this SO link: [automating decompile / recompile in ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338443/automating-decompile-recompile-in-ms-access)
2. Compact & Repair at least daily while developing your application
3. **Backup!** Do this at least for every significant revision. Sometimes, the Access front-end will become so corrupt that it trashes all of your work. When this happens, nothing is recoverable.

Comment: Thank you!  So it seems there is no way to avoid some issues with Access.  The best thing to do is just be prepared for when it happens I take it?

Comment: Correct: 'Stable Programming Environment' <> 'Microsoft Access'. Also, Parfait and AVG have good recommendations that should be followed. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Your system should be split into two files. FE(front end) containing all forms, queries, code, etc., linked to the BE. BE(back end) containing the data tables only.
Maintain a development copy of the FE that is only used for making modifications.
Each user should have their own copy of the FE on their local machine. If you don't know how to split, just search for it as there are plenty of instructions out there.

Comment: I will definitely research that!  Thank you